# Facebook\Google login with aws cognito user pool

Tags: java, android, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am applying Facebook with CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider but user entry added in identity pool not in user pool. I need to get JWT token for auth. I did research  on lots of document but no one give proper solution. Please help me how to achieve social login with aws cognito.

```
Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<String, String>();
logins.put("graph.facebook.com", accessToken.getToken());
provider.setLogins(logins);
```

Comment: Did you get  the  answer ?

Comment: Yes, try with endpoint url.